# What is the $p$-completion of a space?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology

How is the $p$-completion of a topological space made? I can't find a paper or a book where it is explained, so I will appreciate if anyone answers me with an explanation of how the $p$-completion is done and (optionally) references to read about it.

Comment: This is almost certainly either done in May's "concise algebraic topology" or its sequel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have several books at your disposal for this. Possible references are:

- Bousfield and Kan, *Homotopy limits, completions and localizations*. **/!\ Warning /!\** Contrary to what one might believe, you need to start with the second part of this book to have a chance of understanding the first one!
- May and Ponto, *More concise algebraic topology*. This is the sequel to May's book *A concise course in algebraic topology* that Mike Miller mentioned in the comments.

The basic idea of completion is that you want to study your topological space "one prime at a time" basically. Just like you might want to study an abelian group by studying first its 2-torsion, then its 3-torsion... and so on, and then the torsion free part, then you might also want to do the same for a topological space.

If I give you a topological space $X$ then all the information is jumbled together, but if you $p$-complete it then you get a new topological space that only retains the "mod $p$" information of $X$, whatever that might mean -- for example you only keep the mod $p$ (co)homology, but it's more than that. And since there's also a "torsion-free" part, you also want to consider the rationalization of $X$, that only keeps the information over $\mathbb{Q}$. You can now study all these parts independently, and you can mix them back together to have information about $X$.

Note that there is also something called "$p$-localization" of a space. Both topics are generally treated at the same time (both of the books I mentioned do both), the difference with $p$-completion is [a difference of finiteness](https://mathoverflow.net/q/215467/36146).

Comment: Just as you said, I was trying to read the Bousfield and Kan paper, and it was hard since they use the loop group functor and other things I didn't know. Each time I read a bit, I had to go back to understand what they used. That's because I wanted to ask in case it is a nice book or paper to understand it better.